# Piranha CMS Custom Entities

Tags: piranha-cms

I am new the Piranha. I want to make a new table in database like as site messages or newsletter form.

Can I make extension or what is the right way for Piranha?

Additional info: I am not using source code. I add piranha to my project from Nu-get.

Answer (score 0):

just add entities/tables to your database using entity framework or whatever technology you like.

Remember that if you use an ORM you will can't have foreign key to tables in other contexts (Piranha) so you'll have to handle relationships with software triggers.

Regards

Håkan

Comment: Thanks Håkan, I was add table before your ways but i want to learn is it best way..